# What is the name of those clothes

Tags: word-request, image-identification

I just come to the U.S. not long ago, and I have trouble finding the names of clothes. Anyways, in this picture:

[image: Clothes]

What are these:

- The inner black shirt
- The outer shirt
- The black shoes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The inner shirt would be called a *T-shirt*. Outside of that is a *black jacket*. The black shoes are just that: *black shoes*.

We might further qualify those basic terms with added descriptions. We might call it a *black V-necked T-shirt* (if it was made of cotton). If it was made of wool we might call it a *black V-necked sweater*.

The black jacket (not a shirt) would be described a collarless, or perhaps small collared, or up-turned collar; it also has a single button and upturned cuffs. Some would call that "popped collar cool". Someone might be able to recognise the particular designers style and name it as such.

The shoes could be qualified as "black leather men's slip-on shoes".

Comment: I don't think we have a good enough picture of the shoes to say they are anything other than "black shoes". The toe and heel make me think they're boots, but I can't tell from the picture.

Comment: On the T-shirt/sweater distinction, it's not so much the type of fiber (cotton/wool) that would distinguish the two (as I have cotton sweaters, and both can come in synthetic fibers - wool T-shirts are rare) but rather the type of fabric and size of the yarn. Sweaters are almost always a looser knit of comparatively large yarn, whereas T-shirts are either tight knit or woven from a thin yarn/thread. -- Though the sleeves (if not hidden by the jacket) would be the give-away. T-shirts have short sleeves, whereas sweaters have full sleeves (or no sleeves for "sweater vests").

Comment: If the jacket had a normal collar (and perhaps a few more buttons) it would be a "sport coat" or "blazer".  A little hard to tell what sort of inner shirt is being worn, but "tee shirt" is a good guess.  (There's a vague possibility it's a sleeveless "wife beater".)

Answer (score 3):

His shirt would best be described as a [black v-neck tee shirt](https://www.google.com/search?q=v-neck&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinuKW1r-PSAhXo7YMKHekxCJUQ_AUIBigB&biw=939&bih=699#tbm=isch&q=black%20v-neck&*), though in casual speak you could just call it a v-neck. Over it he is wearing [black blazer](https://www.google.com/search?q=black%20blazer&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj61ISDsOPSAhXExYMKHR14CwsQ_AUIBygC&biw=939&bih=699#imgrc=_), which is similar to suit jackets and sportcoats, and is somewhere between the two in dressiness. You can read about those distinctions [here](https://www.josbank.com/sportcoat-vs-blazer-vs-suit-jacket). Lastly his shoes are [black leather dress (or formal) shoes](https://www.google.com/search?q=black%20leather%20shoes&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxyqrkr-PSAhUK74MKHUb0AEkQ_AUIBygC&biw=939&bih=699#tbm=isch&q=black%20formal%20leather%20shoes&*).